# An unhandled exception occurred: readConfiguration is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to convert one of my Angular10 project to Angular12. These are the steps i followed to convert my Angular10 project to Angular12.

I uninstalled older version of angular-cli
I installed a newer updated version of angular-cli
Now, When I try to do ng serve it gave me the error as stated below.
Please correct me if i am not following the correct steps to upgrade to Angular12

This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!

---

An unhandled exception occurred: readConfiguration is not a function

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Follow this link https://update.angular.io/ and choosing v<version> from:to will show you steps to update your angular application. Let me know if that helps you thx